# Unable to add 1024px app store icon to watchOS app assets

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I've just written a Apple Watch companion app for an iOS app and wanted to upload the new build to iTunes Connect through Xcode, but I get the following warning:

> A 1024x1024 app store icon is required for watchOS apps

This is also the reason why my upload to iTunes Connect fails.

However, all required sizes in the "AppIcon" asset of the watch app are populated and there is no "App Store" size like there is in the iOS app icon asset:

[image: screenshot]

**So where should I add the 1024x1024 app store icon?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found a solution:

In the Assets.xcassets do right-click > App Icons & Launch Images > New watchOS App Icon. This will generate a new app icon asset which includes the "App Store" size.

Make sure to remove the old app icon asset and rename the new one to "AppIcon".

Answer (score 0):

From release notes of Xcode 9.1, it’s a known issue.

> WatchKit App Store icons in the asset catalog are not uploaded when
>   using Xcode to submit an app to the App Store.

**Solution:** Use the iTunes Connect to upload WatchKit App Store icons.

**Edit:** This bug doesn't appear in Xcode 9.3-beta3 anymore. So it should be fixed in Xcode 9.3

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.3. But it seems like this was a different bug anyway, the app icon asset just was incorrectly generated

Comment: Okay, you didn't mention your xcode version that's why I thought it's that common issue... anyway congratulations that you found your own solution.